# Is there any way to if/else a block in jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to made a crude store front app in Express and im trying to set it up so that if a person is logged in so the username is not 'undefined', it shows one block, and if you're logged out it shows another.

Here's my `layout.jade` file:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
      h1.main= title
        body
          - if (typeof(username) !== 'undefined') {
            block items
          -}
          - else {
            block content
          -}
```

My content block contents.

```
extends layout

block content

  #content
    img#splash(src='images/ninja.png')
```

And my items block.

```
block items

     #items
       h1 Hello (username)
```

When I log in, I just see the pages title (my layout.jade files contents) and not the content of the items.jade file.

Does anyone know why this is? I'm new to Express and can't work it out :/

If I do something like.

```
- if (typeof(username) !== 'undefined') {
        p test
      -}
      - else {
        block content
      -}
```

Then I can see the text upon logging in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct but are you passing `username` when rendering the jade file. jade is rendered by your express server in return to a request and if else code is executed when rendering happens.

If you login (set username) or logout after the page is displayed then the block will not be displayed/updated. In your app, you can pass the username while rendering

```
res.render('layout', {locals:{title: 'Page title', username: "something"}});
//display block content
res.render('layout', {locals:{title: 'Page title'}});
//display block items
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [underscore.Js](http://underscorejs.org/) To better manage and map html to Jade, it's best to functions

In the file config express or connect

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
       res.locals._ = require('underscore');
       next();
    });
```

In index.jade

```
    doctype 5
    html
      head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
          h1.main= title
            body
              if _.isUndefined( username )
              //- if _.isString( username ) or bla...
                block items
              else
                block content
```

It is much better, and you can do interesting things!

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your posts. Kindly let the mods know if you have a problem.